# Line Chart Rectangle Annotation resize acording to the point counts

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, annotations, linechart

I have a line chart. I read a value and its recording time from a database and add those to line chart every second. So my points increases every second.

The problem is that. I added a line and rectangle annonation to my line chart. Line annonation stay at same width as it had at the beginning but rectangle annonation's width changes acording to the points' count i have added.

Like this;

[image]
[image]

I just want that rectangle annonation have a fixed width How can i do that?

Code;

```
    VerticalLineAnnotation VA;
    RectangleAnnotation RA;
    double xFactor = 0.03;
    double yFactor = 0.02;


    VA = new VerticalLineAnnotation();
    VA.AxisX = chartMonitor.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
    VA.AllowMoving = true;
    VA.IsInfinitive = true;
    VA.ClipToChartArea = chartMonitor.ChartAreas[0].Name;
    VA.Name = "myLine";
    VA.LineColor = Color.Red;
    VA.LineWidth = 2;
    VA.X = 1;


    RA = new RectangleAnnotation();
    RA.AxisX = chartMonitor.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
    RA.IsSizeAlwaysRelative = false;
    RA.Width = 10 * xFactor;
    RA.Height = 30 * yFactor;
    VA.Name = "myRect";
    RA.LineColor = Color.Red;
    RA.BackColor = Color.Red;
    RA.AxisY = chartMonitor.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
    RA.Y = -RA.Height;
    RA.X = VA.X - RA.Width / 2;

    RA.Text = "M1";
    RA.ForeColor = Color.White;
    RA.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8f);

    chartMonitor.Annotations.Add(VA);
    chartMonitor.Annotations.Add(RA);
    chartMonitor.AnnotationPositionChanged += new EventHandler(chartMonitor_AnnotationPositionChanged);
    chartMonitor.AnnotationPositionChanging += new EventHandler<AnnotationPositionChangingEventArgs>(chartMonitor_AnnotationPositionChanging);

void chartMonitor_AnnotationPositionChanging(object sender, AnnotationPositionChangingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender == VA) RA.X = VA.X - RA.Width / 2;
        }

        void chartMonitor_AnnotationPositionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            VA.X = (int)(VA.X + 0.5);
            RA.X = VA.X - RA.Width / 2;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I remember that piece of code..

The Annotation is bound to the X-Axis, which means most of its Properties are measured in X-Axis values. (Not the LineWidth, though, which is in Pixels or the FontSize, which works as usual..)

I had included a factor to let you scale things as needed.

Assuming a value `f1 = 0.03` works well for `N1` data points you will need to re-calculate for `N2` data points like this:

```
 xFactor = f1 * N1 / N2;
```

So you should introduce a const f1 and re-calculate the factor when you add or remove plot points..

Here is a function that will do that:

```
 void scaleAnnotation(Annotation A)
 {
     ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas[0];// pick your chartarea..
     A.AxisX = CA.AxisX;                 // .. and axis!
     int N = S1.Points.Count;            // S1 being your Series !
     // to keep the label width constant the chart's width must be considered
     // 60 is my 'magic' number; you must adapt for your chart's x-axis scale!
     double xFactor = 60 * N / chart1.Width;   
     A.Width = 1 * xFactor ;
     A.X = VA.X - A.Width / 2;    
 }
```

I found that even when resizing the chart, adding 10.000 points and removing them one by one the label's width is pretty much constant.

Note: You will have to adapt the xFactor to your Chart's x-Values scale; do a few tests..!
I find that calling this every time I add a point keeps the label at a pretty constant size even when the chart itself has hundereds of points.

Comment: But some points dissapper from the line chart if there is too much points added. how can i get number of appearing points?

Comment: _But some points dissapper from the line chart if there is too much points added._ What do you mean by that? Do you have implemented scrolling? The total number of data points in a `Series S` is `n = S.Points.Count`. You need to calculate with the total number of points, not just the added number..

Comment: if there are 5 points for example, when 10 points more are added it automaticly shows the points 1,5,9,13

Comment: That sounds as if you have set the intervall to 4. The datapoints are probably showing in the lines, just the ticks&labels at the bottom are missing, right? You controls the Interval of an axis of a chartarea CA like this `CA.AxisX.Interval = 1;`

Comment: I did not set any interval it is automatic.

Comment: Yes. You can control it both its size and its offset. But no actaul data are missing right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61346/discussion-between-mod-and-taw).